# My form on wordpress page doesn't execute

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms

I have a page made on wordpress with edited by me custom theme.
I've tried to make my own form using ajax without any plugin.
The problem is that I don't have any errors etc. and form still doesn't do anything (just reloads page). I did everything like on tutorial page and still don't know what to do. I figured out that php code doesn't execute. As you can see there are input conditions that doesn't execute :/

This is what i have done so far:

html:

```
<section id="contact_content">
        <form name="contact_me" action="" method="post">
        <?php if( get_field('contact_header') ): ?>
            <div id="contact_header"><?php the_field('contact_header'); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <input type="text" name="form_name" placeholder="<?php the_field('contact_name'); ?>" id="contact_name"> <br />
        <input type="number" name="form_phone_number" placeholder="<?php the_field('contact_phone'); ?>" id="contact_phone"> <br />
        <input type="email" name="form_email" placeholder="<?php the_field('contact_mail'); ?>" id="contact_mail"> <br />
        <input type="text" name="form_comment" placeholder="<?php the_field('contact_message'); ?>" id="contact_message" style="height: 190px;"><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_form" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
        <button type="submit" id="contact_button">wyślij</button>
        </form>
    </section>
```

function.php

```
function javascript_variables(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';
        let ajax_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "secure_nonce_name" ); ?>';
        //form AJAX validation
        $( 'form[name="contact_me"]' ).on( 'submit', function() {
            let form_data = $( this ).serializeArray();

            form_data.push( { "name" : "security", "value" : ajax_nonce } );

            $.ajax({
                url : ajax_url,
                type : 'post',
                data : form_data,
                success : function( response ) {
                    console.log( response );
                },
                fail : function( err ) {
                    console.log( "Błąd: " + err );
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script><?php
}
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'javascript_variables' );
add_action('wp_ajax_send_form', 'send_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form', 'send_form');

function send_form(){

    check_ajax_referer( 'secure-nonce-name', 'security' );

    if ( empty( $_POST["form_name"] ) ) {
        echo "Wprowadź imię i nazwisko.";
        wp_die();
    }
    if ( ! filter_var( $_POST["form_email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
        echo "Wprowadź poprawny adres e-mail.";
        wp_die();
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST["form_comment"] ) ) {
        echo "Wprowadź wiadomość.";
        wp_die();
    }
    if ( empty($_POST["form_phone_number"] ) ) {
        echo 'Wprowadź numer telefonu';
        wp_die();
    }

    $to = 'dawidt9882@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Now message from a client!';

    $body  = 'From: ' . $_POST['form_name'] . '\n';
    $body .= 'Number: ' . $_POST['form_phone_number'] . '\n';
    $body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['form_email'] . '\n';
    $body .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['form_comment'] . '\n';

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

    echo 'Wiadomość została wysłana! ;p';
    wp_die();
}
```

Any ideas? :c

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( 'form[name="contact_me"]' ).on( 'submit', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        let form_data = $( this ).serializeArray();

        form_data.push( { "name" : "security", "value" : ajax_nonce, "action" : "send_form" } );

        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
            data : form_data,
            success : function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
            },
            fail : function( err ) {
                console.log( "Błąd: " + err );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: also add action here - `form_data.push( { "name" : "security", "value" : ajax_nonce, "action" : "send_form" } );`

Comment: i was certain that was it :/ I was looking for something to put php function in but it still doesn't work ;c

Comment: change submit to click and use preventdefault

Comment: Changed as you said with no result :/ I pasted code above.

Comment: you should add onclick on button, not on form

Comment: think got it - rollback to submit and add echo before script

Comment: I rollbacked submit, but could you show me which way should I add echo before script? :)

Comment: yes - you've done it, will check later and add the solution here

Answer (score 0):

So now js looks like this:

```
        let ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';
        let ajax_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "secure_nonce_name" ); ?>';
        //form AJAX validation
        $( '#contact_button' ).on( 'click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            let form_data = $( this ).serializeArray();

            form_data.push( { "name" : "security", "value" : ajax_nonce, "action" : "send_form" } );

            $.ajax({
                url : ajax_url,
                type : 'post',
                data : form_data,
                success : function( response ) {
                    console.log( response );
                },
                fail : function( err ) {
                    console.log( "Błąd: " + err );
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script><?php
```

And it still does nothing. :/ If i made a mistake please dissuade me of any notion.